# Controlling print size in IE7

Tags: javascript, printing, internet-explorer-7, activex

It seems that IE7 defaults to "Shink to Fit" on the printing of HTML pages.  Is there a way to control the browser settings/print preview settings using ActiveX thru Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using [MeadCo ScriptX](http://www.meadroid.com/scriptx/) to control printing. They have a free version which exposes a subset of functionality which is enough to control some simple things like margins, headers, etc. You can also purchase a license (if you are an organisation, as it is pretty expensive) and control quite a lot of other page printing parameters.

Comment: Thanks!  I checked this out, and even the free version works very nicely!